# how to alter table column data type

Tags: mysql

I've the following column

```
hits text NOT NULL
```

and want to alter it to

```
hits bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0'
```

how to use ALTER TABLE commands to do this change ! ~ thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY hits bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0';
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [Alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
MODIFY [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
    [FIRST | AFTER col_name]
```

So your query should be:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
MODIFY hits bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try read [alter table syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

```
alter table YourTableName 
change column hits hits bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0';
```